# Webview - setTextSize not working on emulator API level 1-10?

Tags: android, webview

My XML is as follows with regards to SDK version:

```
android:minSdkVersion="3"
android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

Under properties it's setup with the same, as far as i can see in the documentation setTextSize should be working from API level 1?

When i test the app on API level 14 it works fine, however anything below that i've tried the textsize is unchanged.

Hope i've made enough sense, i think im missing something obvious..

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(myapp.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog);
dialog.setTitle("Change font size...");
dialog.setCancelable(true);

//bar = (SeekBar)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_seekbar);
// bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(myapp.this);

Button OK = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button);
OK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      small = (RadioButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.radio_small);
      medium = (RadioButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.radio_medium);
      large = (RadioButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.radio_large);
      if(small.isChecked()){
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.SMALLER);
      }
      else if(medium.isChecked()){
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.NORMAL);
      }
      else if(large.isChecked()){
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.LARGER);
      }
      else {
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: We are having the same problem at API 10. At the moment it looks like we will have to use setDefaultZoom for API <= 10 instead. Unfortunately, this only provides 3 settings.